# If 2 vectors form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, must these 2 vectors always be orthogonal to each other?

Tags: linear-algebra

If 2 vectors form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, must these 2 vectors always be orthogonal to each other?

For instance, the standard bases in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are definitely orthogonal (easily drawn). How about other bases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they definitely need not be orthogonal, just non-parallel.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider $A=\left\{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
\end{array}
\right],\left[
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
2\\
\end{array}
\right]\right\}\subset\mathbb{R^2}$. $A$ is linearly independent and spans $\mathbb{R^2}$, so $A$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R^2}$. However, $\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
\end{array}
\right]$ and $\left[
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
2\\
\end{array}
\right]$ are not orthogonal.